# ffmpeg convert wav to mp3 using php variable

Tags: php, audio, ffmpeg

I am working on a php function to upload a .wav and also create an .mp3 version of it in the same folder. So far everything is working how it should except for when I try using:

```
 shell_exec('ffmpeg -i ' . $file_path . '-f mp2 ' . $mp3name);
```

within the function it isn't creating the .mp3 in the beats folder.

I tried

```
shell_exec('ffmpeg -i test.wav -f mp2 test.mp3');
```

on its own and it worked great.

**php Function:**

```
function upload_a_sound($user_id, $file_temp, $file_extn, $name, $uploader, $keywords) {
    $timecode = substr(md5(time()), 0, 10);
    $mp3name = 'beats/' . $timecode . '.mp3';
    $file_path = 'beats/' . $timecode . '.' . $file_extn;
    //$date = date('m-d-Y');
    move_uploaded_file($file_temp, $file_path);
    shell_exec('ffmpeg -i ' . $file_path . '-f mp2 ' . $mp3name); 
    require ('classAudioFile.php');
    $AF = new AudioFile;
    $AF->loadFile($file_path);
    $AF->visual_width=200;
    $AF->visual_height=200;
    $AF->visual_graph_color="#c491db";
    $AF->visual_background_color="#000000";
    $AF->visual_grid=false;
    $AF->visual_border=false;
    $AF->visual_graph_mode=0;
    $AF->getVisualization ('images/song/' . $timecode . '.png');
    $imageloc = 'images/song/' . $timecode . '.png';
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO `content` VALUES ('', '', '$name', '$uploader', '$keywords', '$file_path', '$imageloc', '$mp3name')");

}
```

Comment: Are you setting `$file_path` and `$mp3name` to `test.wav` and `test.mp3`?

Comment: Hey will, the $file_path and $mp3name are actually being set based on a substring md5 version of the time ($timecode) to keep file names unique in the directory they also have beats/ infront of them. I will try them without all of that with to see if it works and post any updates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working version of code, I believe it was something with the syntax where I had to put a ' after $mp3name shell execute

```
function upload_a_sound($user_id, $file_temp, $file_extn, $name, $uploader, $keywords) {
    $timecode = substr(md5(time()), 0, 10);
    $mp3name = 'beats/' . $timecode . '.mp3';
    $wavname = 'beats/' . $timecode . '.wav';
    $file_path = 'beats/' . $timecode . '.' . $file_extn;
    //$date = date('m-d-Y');
    move_uploaded_file($file_temp, $file_path);
    shell_exec('ffmpeg -i ' . $wavname . ' -vn -ar 44100 -ac 2 -ab 192k -f mp3 ' . $mp3name . ''); 
    require ('classAudioFile.php');
    $AF = new AudioFile;
    $AF->loadFile($file_path);
    $AF->visual_width=200;
    $AF->visual_height=200;
    $AF->visual_graph_color="#c491db";
    $AF->visual_background_color="#000000";
    $AF->visual_grid=false;
    $AF->visual_border=false;
    $AF->visual_graph_mode=0;
    $AF->getVisualization ('images/song/' . $timecode . '.png');
    $imageloc = 'images/song/' . $timecode . '.png';
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO `content` VALUES ('', '', '$name', '$uploader', '$keywords', '$file_path', '$imageloc', '$mp3name')");
```

Comment: Let me make one suggestion also! Instead of `$wavname` and `$mp3name`, use `escapeshellarg($wavname)` and `escapeshellarg($mp3name)`. This prevents security issues and also will keep the command working properly if there are special characters in either name. Similarly, I also recommend you look into [MySQLi](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) and [Prepared Statements](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).

Comment: Hey Will, Thanks! I really have to get into MySQLi! I have been using mysql so long even though its deprecated. I appreciate your help!

Comment: No problem, best of luck! If you get stuck trying to get MySQLi working, just post another question, or see if there are any existing ones covering your issues. In PHP7, the `mysql_*()` functions are gone completely. Also you should accept your own answer to mark it as solved.